# Difference between dynamic web project and enterprise application project

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the difference between a dynamic web project and an enterprise application project in Eclipse IDE ?

Can I directly create a dynamic web project in eclipse if I want to use both normal JSP (with Java classes) and Java Server Faces (with Java Classes)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamic Web Project:

- Requires only a servlet container - usually provided by a web server like Tomcat, Jetty, etc.
- Can't use "enterprise features" like the EJB container

Enterprise Application Project:

- Requires a servlet container
- Requires an EJB container, JMS container, etc. - so called "enterprise features", provided by enterprise application servers like Wildfly.

If you need a project, that will use JSP + JSF, you are perfectly fine with a dynamic web project.

Comment: Thanks man :) 
So, the default configuration while creating the dynamic web project, I select Java Server Faces v2.2 ?

Comment: Yes, that should automatically include the needed dependencies in the project.